# Laravel artisan optimize not creating bootstrap/compiled

Tags: php, optimization, laravel, laravel-4

I used to have a `bootstrap/compiled.php` file. Then I accidentally deleted it, and because for some reason it was in .gitignore, I don't have another copy of it. How do I get it back?

I tried running `compose dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize`, neither of these generated the file. Where does it come from? How do I produce it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Laravel 4.1+ does not create `bootstrap/compiled.php` on development boxes anymore, only in 'production'.  Actually Laravel checks if debug mode is `on` if it is, it will not generate the compiled.php.

But you can:

```
php artisan optimize --force
```

To force its creation.

Comment: Mr. Ribeiro, how does Laravel recognizes I'm in production? Is it by the environment name?

Comment: Actually it's not really in production, it's debug mode, if it's `on` you probably are still in development.

Answer (score 0):

Switch debug mode to false in **app/config/app.php** and run your command again.

```
'debug' => false,
```